# Downloaded user numbers are too high, while other metrics numbers are spot on

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For downloading Data from Google Analytics I use RStudio (R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)) with the following code:

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
library(RGA)

gaData4_5 <- ga$getData(profileId, 
                    start.date = as.Date("2017-01-04"), 
                    end.date=as.Date("2017-01-05"),
                    metrics = "ga:impressions,ga:adCost,ga:adClicks,ga:users",
                    dimensions = "ga:date,ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:adwordsAdGroupID", filter = "ga:source==google,ga:medium==cpc", 
                    sort = "ga:date", batch = TRUE)
```

When summing up impression, adCost und adClicks, the numbers in R match exactly the numbers that are shown onthe Analytics Web site itself. However, only the number of users is too high and I do not understand why.

I checked also newUsers, and userType (not in the above code), but neither of these alternatives provided the correct result.

Can anyone please explain, how it can happen that 3 metrics results are perfectly correct, only one is not? And what can be done to correct this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot simply do summation of `users` metric. Have a look at [How the Users metric is calculated](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en)

Comment: Excellent - thanks a million. I wasn't aware of this.